# How to filter an array items stored in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, lodash

I am looking for a best way to implement a method which goal is to check if the string stored in the array includes a substring.

`const arrayOfObj = [ {name: 'Tom', jobsPositions: ['general manager', 'staff manager', 'director']} ]`

Let's assume I have a 100 persons in arrayOfObj. I have something like this:

```
arrayOfObj.filter(person => person.jobsPositions.some(position => position.includes('manager')));
```

The reslt should be the new array with all persons which have at least one job position with a 'manager' word.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: to do that usually I work with filter with the array and ```string.search(mysubstring)``` if it return -1 the substring isn't in the string else it will return the index

Comment: Yep but it would be related to the very last part of this. `string.search(mysubstring)` instead of `position.includes('manager')` and moreover I would need to check the result if it is not a -1

Comment: no, it's as good as it can get. What you could do eventually to avoid repeated query searches is to safe the results in a object, where the keys are the substrings which has the found ids. this way you could check at the object if that query has already the results before doing your filter search

Comment: @Franz what do you mean with "better way to achive this?", are you looking for more performance? or better time complexity?

Comment: @FatihTurgut I was wondering if this can be implemented in a more simplified way. Time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
const arrayOfObj = [
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    jobsPositions: [
      'general manager',
      'staff manager',
      'director',
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Joe',
    jobsPositions: [
      'director',
    ],
  },
];
arrayOfObj.filter(person => person.jobsPositions.some(position => position.includes('manager')));
```

For your code, i can say its time complexity is O(M * N * L) for worst-case

- **M**: .filter() iterates over each element,
- **N**: .some() iterates over each element,
- **L**: .includes() iterates over the inner array,

You may beautify code and make more readable with the **hasJobPositionManager** function

```
const hasJobPositionManager = person => person.jobsPositions.some(position => position.includes('manager'))
arrayOfObj.filter(hasJobPositionManager);
```

But I couldn't find the better **time complexity** and **readable code** for this code, i also use like yours.

Comment: as a side note `some` and `includes` exit immediately with the first matching condition.